# I am getting error "Error: Could not find a part of the path'"

Tags: c#, ssis

I am getting an error in this code, trying to move my file.

Error is:

> Could not find a part of the path

Code:

```
 public void Main()
 {
     string fullpath = Dts.Variables["User::FoldeName"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
        
     if (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fullpath).Length > 0)
     {
         Dts.Variables["User::IfFileExists"].Value = true;
     }
     else
     {
         Dts.Variables["User::IfFileExists"].Value = false;
     }
    
     Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
    
#region ScriptResults declaration
/// <summary>
/// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
/// result of the script.
/// 
/// This code was generated automatically.
/// </summary>
enum ScriptResults
{
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
};
#endregion
```

Fixed the formatting of code.

Comment: Could it be that the directory of fullPath does not exist? Easy to check in code with Directory.Exists(fullPath)

Comment: at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)

Comment: It's not the full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I'm will wager dollars to dumpling' it's the first line of main.

If you were to add these lines and run the package, in your output, you'd see the values of concatenating those two variables at run-time: `User::FoldeName` (assuming that's not a typo) and `User::FileName`.

This is going to fire an Information to the Results tab and the Output window so you can inspect what the current value of a variable is without dealing with breakpoints or MessageBox.

```
        bool fireAgain = false;
        string message = "{0}::{1}";
        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format(message, "fullpath", fullpath), "", 0, ref fireAgain);
```

What's happening?  You're building your path by hand by concatenating variables which you, the gentle reader, should not do because you're going to mess it up.  Instead, trust the fine engineers in Redmond and [use System.IO.Path.Combine](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/03/yes-virgina-there-is-net-path-builder.html)

```
string fullpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Dts.Variables["User::FoldeName"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString());
```

My assumption here is that your FoldeName variable does *not* have a trailing space on it, nor does the FileName variable have a leading slash. Combine is going to handle putting the correct folder delimiter in there. Things change and now FoldeName does have a trailing slash, `Combine` is smart enough to not add an extra.